# Div with two classes only pulling css from one?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Okay, so I'm setting up a template for a site and I'm using the header and footer html/css that is pre-existing (written by someone else).

I took their css file and formatted it so it'd be easier to read, but other than that I haven't made any changes to it.  I ran it through a validator as well.

But for some reason, when I link MY formatted version of the css to the template, the site breaks.  When I use theirs, it works.

HERE'S the weird problem, though ... It's pulling some styling.  Specifically, I have one div with two classes assigned:

```
<div class="publication-footer-id text-publication-400-12px">
     <div class="text-publication-700-12px">title</div>
     <div class="text-publication-400-12px">link</div>  
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.text-publication-400-12px, .text-publication-400-12px a {
    font-family:'Montserrat-Regular',serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.text-publication-700-12px, .text-publication-700-12px a {
    font-family:'Montserrat-Bold',serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.text-publication-400-12px {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px;
}

.text-publication-400-12px a {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px;
    color:#666666;
}

.text-publication-700-12px {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666666;
}

.publication-footer-da, .publication-footer-id, .publication-footer-cced {
    padding:10px 0 0 20px;
    float:left;
    height:120px;
    color:#666666;
}

.publication-footer-id {
    width:13%;
    border-right:solid 1px #989898;
}
```

And THIS is the original CSS styled by the other person:

```
.text-publication-700-12px{font-family:'Montserrat-Bold', serif; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; color:#666666;}
.text-publication-700-12px a { color: #666666;}
.text-publication-400-12px{font-family:'Montserrat-Regular', serif; font-weight:regular;font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; line-height:16px;}
.text-publication-400-12px a{font-family:'Montserrat-Regular', serif; font-weight:regular;font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; line-height:16px; color:#666666;}

.publication-footer-id{width:13%; height:121px; float:left; border-right:solid 1px #989898; color:#666666; padding:10px 0 0 21px;}
```

Soo for some reason, when I link MY css file, the "publication-footer-id text-publication-400-12px" div is ONLY pulling the style from the "text-publication-400-px" class, and none of the styling from the "publication-footer-id" class.  Yet it works fine with the other CSS.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:  Just wanted to add that I notice it's only pulling one style by right clicking, inspect element ... When I look at the CSS being applied to that Div, it's only showing the publication text styling.

Comment: They look exactly the same on fiddles: [#1 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1xLwmja/) / [#2 fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g05zwdc7/) Maybe a cache issue?

Comment: I've tried that - gone into Chrome and completely eradicated all browsing data and the problem persists. :/  It doesn't make any sense to me, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatter looks buggy.. or you accidentally edited some parts.

Take a look at `.publication-footer-id` class: in original file it declares width, height, float, border-right, color and padding. In formatted version it declares only width and border-right.

Almost the same for all other classes, you miss a lot of declarations.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that.  In my CSS I've simply combined certain classes' elements (width, height, float) into one node, and then added specifics to each class with another, separate one.